# how to operate an app running on two tablets from on tablet in android

Tags: java, android

I am working on app running on two tablets, which have two type of logins. Customer and Shopkeeper, it will run on two tabs at same time. I am getting tabs device id and saving it. because it can't be run on any other tablet without registered tablets.The issue is that after login when I go on main  screen, when i enter number from any tablets, the next screen must be changed on both tablets. I am not getting the idea how to operate two tabs from any one of them.Can you help me to get this idea. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: So, in summary you want to sync the state between two app on different tablet?

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 separate options here :

**A. Use CouchDB.**

[Couch DB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) has this functionality to sync data between client and server.
   Steps :

1. Tablet1 enter a value
2. Value saved in tablet1 CouchDB. (You can use something like [couchbase-android](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/Android-Couchbase))
3. Data synced from client COUCHDB to Server CouchDB ( you can use [Cloudant](https://cloudant.com/) here )
4. Data synced from Server CouchDB to client CouchDB in the Tablet1
5. Tablet2 use a listener to listen to record change in the database
6. Tablet2 change its state based on the record change.

**B. Use Notification Server**

1. Tablet1 enter a value
2. Tablet1 send message to Notification Server, indicating the changes
3. Notification Server send notification to Tablet2
4. Tablet2 use [Notification Listener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html) to listen to all notification
5. Tablet2 change it state based on data contained in the notification message.